# pywinauto scripts run so slow now, they were running very well and fast

Tags: pywinauto

I am currently doing desktop automation by using pywinauto. I have done many tests automated and they were running successfully and fast. But suddenly they started to run too slow, 1 seconds step is running in 2-3 mins. For example, entering username takes 2-3 mins or more. I run automated regression tests after getting new version of desktop apps.

I need help, what should I do?

I reinstalled Python 3.10.6 , Pywinauto and pywinauto-recorder but still same.

Comment: Maybe some Windows update hotfixes and .NET framework updates are necessary if newer apps rely on some new features or fixes and have slow workarounds for old API. But we can only guess. Which kind of apps and underlying frameworks (WPF, Qt?) are used? For example, I remember issues in some (pretty old) Qt versions with infinite hierarchy. Who knows what happens in some newer version.